# Running .exe from Java gives different console output then running .exe directly from Windows

Tags: java, c#, windows, eclipse, exe

So this one is a bit strange - Why running .exe file from Java gives different output as opposed to running .exe directly.

When java executes below line, it invokes an .exe file which i have build that works with 3CX phone system.

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("3cx-api-application/orderly-3cx.exe");
```

When the code is executed from java/eclipse/jar file the below error is printed.

```
INFO: 3CX Initialization Started
Jun 08, 2017 1:58:19 PM com.orderlysoftware.threecx.Orderly3CXConnector threeCXinit
INFO: Sending: Initializing 3cx-Orderly Connector
Jun 08, 2017 1:58:28 PM com.orderlysoftware.threecx.Orderly3CXConnector threeCXinit
SEVERE: SEVERE: 
Jun 08, 2017 1:58:28 PM com.orderlysoftware.threecx.Orderly3CXConnector threeCXinit
SEVERE: SEVERE: Unhandled Exception: TCX.Configuration.Exceptions.PhoneSystemException: ConfigServer is not connected
Jun 08, 2017 1:58:28 PM com.orderlysoftware.threecx.Orderly3CXConnector threeCXinit
SEVERE: SEVERE:    at TCX.Configuration.PhoneSystem.Connect()
```

Now when i navigate to the .exe file directly by going into 3cx-api-application and clicking on orderly-3cx.exe program is executed just fine, giving me below output.

**Note:** the 'initializing 3cx-orderly connector' line on both outputs.

```
Initializing 3cx-Orderly Connector
Program Initialized
Initialize Monitor
*0 NOT REGISTEREDVMB(0/0)
a length: 0
*1 NOT REGISTEREDVMB(0/0)
a length: 0
```

And what is weirder is that, this used to work in java but now it does not. All the .exe file is supposed to do is connect to 3CX API and print some output to console, this output should then be read by java class.

I have cleaned both projects (eclipse/visual studio), re-compiled all classes etc. Still the same issue

Comment: Your working folder appears to be different. I think in the Java application your working folder will be one level higher than running the exe directly. If the program is looking for a config file or something, this could affect it.

Comment: @RB. the .exe file is looking for config file, but the config file is in the same place as .exe file. Exe already has predefined path for the config - resolving to root directory where Exe it self resides.

Comment: But you're not running the .exe file from the same directory as the .exe file.

Comment: @MaciejCygan Are you sure `resolving to root directory where Exe it self resides` is true? Are you sure it's not `resolving to working directory` (which is more likely)...

Comment: Easy way to test. Navigate in a command prompt to the parent folder of `3cx-api-application` and run the command `3cx-api-application/orderly-3cx.exe`. If you get the same error as you get in Java then I'm almost certainly right :)

Comment: @RB. Yes you are right... its not resolving to root directory where exe is but to working directory. Bagger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executable file reads a config file from the same directory as itself. You need to run the executable from that directory. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.io.File-

Try:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("orderly-3cx.exe", null, "3cx-api-application");
```

(P.S. Oracle's Javadoc recommends that new applications should use ProcessBuilder instead of Runtime.)

Comment: Your syntax is a little off. Should be `.., new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/3cx-api-application"));` however this does not seem to resolve the issue. I still get the error (looks like the working directory is not set correctly?)

Comment: Nevertheless, i have found a neat solution thanks to your suggestion :)